# I tried to create my first django project(using powershell) but failed to do so because of errors

Tags: django, windows, installation

I am new to django. I wanted to create my first sample project so I followed all the usual ways(as in youtube) and installed python 3.4,pip,django etc. When the environment was set I typed the below command in windows powershell

django-admin startproject mysiteone

and got the below syntax error message(See last para)

My system uses Windows 7 OS. I was unable to find even the version of django i had installed. I dont know why.

I gave these codes in powershell:

django-admin startproject mysiteone

python -m django --version

Error message that I got as a result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 171, in _run_module_as_main "_main_", mod_spec)
File "C:\Python34\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin.exe\_main_.py", line 5, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\_init_.py", line 260
subcommands = [*get_commands(), 'help']

SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target
```

Comment: Support for Python 3.4 was dropped in Django 2.1. You need to either install Python >= 3.5 or fallback to Django 2.0.x

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and i solved by migration to python >= 3.5 , it's an unpacking problem => https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/